# How to disable cookies with cookieconsent by Insites

Tags: javascript, cookies

I don't understand: https://cookieconsent.insites.com/documentation/disabling-cookies/

```
onInitialise: function (status) {
  var type = this.options.type;
  var didConsent = this.hasConsented();
  if (type == 'opt-out' && !didConsent) {
    // disable cookies
  }
},
```

What do I have to put instead of "//disable cookies" to disable the cookies?

Answer (score 2):

I think that you could add something like:

```
window['ga-disable-UA-XXXXX-Y'] = true;
```

Inside that section (see [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/user-opt-out)). But it mostly depends your needs and your cookies you set.

Additionally I think that the script could be improved to use

```
  if (navigator.doNotTrack && navigator.doNotTrack === 1) {
    window['ga-disable-{{GA ID}}'] = true;
  }
```

So we could use the "Do not track" option in the browser here. Not sure if that is already covered in the Insites CookieConsent script.

P.S.
Keep noted that there exists currently a small bug (reported [here](https://github.com/insites/cookieconsent/pull/284)).

Answer (score 0):

If you have more analytics and so on, you can do like:

1. Define a function which creates a variable on call:

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript">
       function setOptOut() {
       localStorage.setItem('optout', 'true');
       window.location.reload(false);
       }
   </script>
   ```
2. Insert the call where you find //disable cookies like:

   ```
   setOptOut()
   ```
3. Load scripts only if not opted out:

   ```
   if (!localStorage.getItem('optout')) {
   //your tracking scripts
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I've made some chrome extension, feel free to use it

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wt8NOtzGdds